# iOS search bar displace

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

I am developing an iPad (iOS7) app which has following screen. On the top right side of the map I have added UITableView and a search bar and search display. But when I try to type on the search bar, it is just moving to top navigation bar as illustrated on the second screenshot. I am using storyboard to develop these interfaces. I want to stay the search bar within the tableview. Could you please help me to overcome this?

1) Initial View
[image: Initial view]

2) Just after starting to type on the search bar
[image: Just after starting to type on the search bar]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are using UISerchDisplayController, it's an easy way to implement search functionalities, but with custom interfaces is a pain.
 In my opinion is better that you manage search by yourself. Or you can try with [UISearchDisplayDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but on iOS7 I had a lot of main issues trying to change the searchTableView according to the app design.
In the first 2 methods I try to change the frame of the search tvc returned from the search display controller. In iOS7 this code is almost useless, they changed something internally.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{

    NSLog(@"Old frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(oldTableViewFrame));
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    self.receiptsTableView.frame= self.view.bounds;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    self.receiptsTableView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.x+self.imageContentView.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height-self.imageContentView.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope: (NSString*)scopes[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:scopes[searchOption]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me any sample code you have coded?

Comment: You are correct. If I add only the search bar, then I don't have this issue. I will try to implement the rest.

Comment: Added code from an old app of mine, that changes the search tvc frame, but in iOS7 doesn't work anymore.

Comment: i think the recommended way is using `[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion]`

Answer (score 1):

the point is when you touch on `UISearchBar`, its default behaviour kicks in (move to the left, add cancel button ...)

so you have to override it.

this is not a perfect solution but you can either use `UISearchBarDelegate` and implement these methods:

`searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` and `searchBarDidBeginEditing:` (im not sure, you have to try both)

or `UISearchDisplayDelegate` with:

```
– searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:
– searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:

– searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:
– searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:
```

set its frame to your desired position when the users begin and end their search.

Comment: Do you know which property I have to override on search bar?